# Codesign verification failed iOS in Xamarin

Tags: ios, xcode, xamarin, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

I'm trying to submit iOS app to App store and I created a `production ID` and `provision profile` and followed the steps in in the thread :
http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/app_distribution_overview/publishing_to_the_app_store/

Then i built the application and it built successfully and then i did archive from `Build->Archive` and it is successful also.

Now when i tried to validate it gave me a message:

> **info:plist**:The following icon is missing from your App **bundle:57X57**.You must reference this icon in **CFBundleIcons** or **CFBndleIconFiles.**

I already selected an icon for the App Icon in `plist` for the `IOS7,8` 120x120 since it is targeting `7.0` and later and it is there and i tested on devices and simulator but it asks me to provide 57x57.

I then added a `57x57` icon and rebuilt all and validated again ,it gave me the :

> **'Codesign verification failed'** with no clarification.

I tried to change the app icon source to AppIcons where the icons are moved folder `Resources/Images.xcassest/AppIcons.appiconset` but still getting the same message .
I tried to rebuilt and checked all names and tested the app over and over again but nothing .

I also want to know if it is possible to validate in xamarin and then submit from Xcode ? I read this somewhere on the net but not steps were provided ?

Appreciate any help